# shouldStartLoadWithRequest: not called for images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I have a `UIWebView` and I make it load an HTML string. The string contains http urls to images. The images get loaded, but `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method is not called for them. It is called just once, for `about : blank`. However all the image requests are successfully passed into my `NSURLCache` subclass, into `cachedResponseForRequest:` method. But I would like to handle the requests in the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` method. Can anything be done about that? How can I make these requests go into the delegate method?

Here is the code:

```
@interface URLCache : NSURLCache

@end

@implementation URLCache

- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSLog(@"REQUEST = %@", request.URL);

    return [super cachedResponseForRequest:request];
}

@end

@interface ViewController ()<UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:[URLCache new]];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                              error:nil];

    self.webView.delegate = self;

   [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
 }

 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   NSLog(@"URL = %@", request.URL);

   return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method is called only for page loads (that is, when the page as a whole gets loaded or when a frame's contents get loaded), not when loading individual resources such as images, JavaScript, or CSS.

If you want to manipulate all HTTP/HTTPS requests from a `UIWebView`, the only way I'm aware of to do so is by using a custom `NSURLProtocol` subclass.  See Apple's [Custom HTTP Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/Read_Me_About_CustomHTTPProtocol_txt.html) sample code project for an example of how to do this.